# Add an URL of list item and add it as a link to the button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I broke my head trying to get an URL value of a list item in my list  and add it to the Add to Cart button so that when the user choose an item "20 items" its URL is added to the Add to Cart button url.

For example if the list item "20 items" (`<li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35435">20 items</a></li>`) the Add to cart button should follow to the link `https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35435`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35435">20 items</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35436">30 items</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35437">50 items</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35438">100 items</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Add to cart</a>
```

Unfortunately my understanding of javascript is really bad at the moment so I can't understand how to do that on my own. I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On click of the anchor tag get its href and use jquery `attr` to update the href of the `Add to Cart` anchor tag

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#test').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35435">20 items</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35436">30 items</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35437">50 items</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35438">100 items</a></li>
</ul>
<a id='test' href="" class="btn btn-danger">Add to cart</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should use some backend script to get params using GET or POST
For example if i am using PHP my code will be like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/cart.php?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35435">20 items</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/cart.php?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35436">30 items</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/cart.php?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35437">50 items</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.example.com/cart.php?add-to-cart=193&variation_id=35438">100 items</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Add to cart</a>
```

on cart.php you have to use $_GET["add-to-cart"] & $_GET["variation_id"] to get both the variables

This scenario redirects user to different page. you can also use ajax if you want to perform action without redirection